# Выпадающее меню не показывает подменю и закрывается при клике

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, адаптивная-верстка

Всем привет! Вопрос в адаптивной версии бургер меню.  При адаптиве при нажатии на пункт меню, меню закрывается, но при нажатии на ссылку "Выпадающее меню" все меню тоже закрывается, а должно открывать список под меню.
Я только изучаю Js. Если вам не сложно можете написать правильный код JS и сделать такой же код только на Jquery.
Заранее спасибо.

```
 <header class="header">
  <a href="#" class="logo">LOGO</a>
  <div class="menu-btn">
    <div class="menu-btn__lines"></div>
  </div>
  <ul class="menu-items">
    <li><a href="#" class="menu-item">Home</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="menu-item expand-btn">Dropdown Menu</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu expandable">
        <li><a href="#" class="menu-item">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="menu-item">Item 2</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown dropdown-right">
          <a href="#" class="menu-item expand-btn">
            Item 3
            <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>
          </a>
          <ul class="menu-right expandable">
            <li><a href="#" class="menu-item">Item 3.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="menu-item">Item 3.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="menu-item">Item 3.3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="menu-item">Item 3.4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="menu-item">Item 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  
    <li><a href="#" class="menu-item">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

---

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  background: #09131b;
  color: #ffffff;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

/* header */
.header {
  background: #122331;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 80vw;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  z-index: 1;
}
.header a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.header ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.logo {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
.menu-items {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.menu-items li {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.menu-items li:hover {
  background-color: #ff652f;
}

/* dropdown */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown-menu,
.menu-right {
  position: absolute;
  background: #122331;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.menu-right {
  top: 0;
  left: 110%;
}
.menu-item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  top: 34px;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
.dropdown-right:hover .menu-right {
  left: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

/* nav menu button */
.menu-btn {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
}
.menu-btn__lines::before,
.menu-btn__lines::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
}
.menu-btn__lines,
.menu-btn__lines::before,
.menu-btn__lines::after {
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 0.1rem;
  background: #ffffff;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.menu-btn__lines::before {
  transform: translateY(-0.5rem);
}
.menu-btn__lines::after {
  transform: translateY(0.5rem);
}
/* animation */
.menu-btn.open .menu-btn__lines {
  transform: translateX(2rem);
  background: transparent;
}
.menu-btn.open .menu-btn__lines::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-1.5rem, 1.5rem);
  background: #ffffff;
}
.menu-btn.open .menu-btn__lines::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-1.5rem, -1.5rem);
  background: #ffffff;
}

/* MEDIA QUERY */
@media screen and (max-width: 970px) {

  .menu-btn {
    display: flex;
  }

  .header .menu-items {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 350px;
    top: 100%;
    right: 0;
    background: #122331;
    display: block;
    padding: 1rem;
    line-height: 3rem;
    overflow-y: auto;
    transform: translateY(-100vh);
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
  }

  .menu-items.open {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }

  .menu-items li {
    margin: 15px 10px;
  }
  .menu-items li a {
    padding: 0 1rem;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
  }
  .menu-items li:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
  }

  /* DROPDOWN, MEGA MENUS */
  .menu-items .dropdown-menu,
  .menu-items .menu-right {
    position: static;
    opacity: 1;
    top: 4rem;
    visibility: visible;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 0;
    transform: scaleY(0);
    transform-origin: top;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
  }
  .expand-btn.open + .expandable {
    max-height: 100%;
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }

  .expandable li {
    margin: 0;
  }
  .expandable li a {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }

}
```

---

```
const menuBtn = document.querySelector(".menu-btn");
const menuItems = document.querySelector(".menu-items");
const expandBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".expand-btn");

// humburger toggle
menuBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  menuBtn.classList.toggle("open");
  menuItems.classList.toggle("open");
});

// mobile menu expand
expandBtn.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    btn.classList.toggle("open");
  });
});

menuItems.onclick = () => {
  menuItems.classList.remove("open");
  menuBtn.classList.remove("open");
};
```

Comment: стили потерял. Без них непонятно что и как у тебя работает

Comment: Все добавил scss

Comment: нет, все равно что-то не то, не работает

Comment: Все изменил. проверил , работает, если тут не работает могу файлы на гитхаб выложить. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот здесь рабочий код: https://jsfiddle.net/my5Lbd7u/30/

твои ошибки:

- Всплывающее меню у тебя вызывается поверх хэдера и это довольно странно. Так что я добавила обертку `<div class="header-wrap">...</div>` чтобы меню проходило *под* ним. Там в стилях посмотришь, ориентируйся на комментарии.

Теперь при клике на бургер, класс добавляется на боди. От него уже можно наследовать все, что нужно и добавлять меню куда угодно.

- при клике на все меню, ты вызываешь функцию закрытия. Поэтому, на те пункты, что должны закрывать меню, надо вешать отдельный класс (например, jsCloseMenu).

  ```
     <li><a href="#" class="menu-item jsCloseMenu">Home</a></li>


    const menuItems = document.querySelectorAll(".jsCloseMenu");
    menuItems.forEach((btn) => {
        btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        document.body.classList.remove('openedMenu')
      });
    });
  ```
- чтобы у тебя меню не было слишком длинным, я его ограничила по высоте:

  ```
    .header .menu-items { max-height: calc(100vh - 80px); }
  ```

там немного не хватает по высоте, сам поправь. 100vh - высота всей страницы минус 80px высота header.

- ну и для красоты я бы добавила скрытие или стилизацию скроллбара. Но это уже сам загугли :)

Comment: Спасибо большое!